# Why is $\left|e^{iat} e^{-st}\right| \le \left| e^{iat}\right| \left| e^{-st}\right| \le e^{-st}$ true?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

My text states:

> $\left|e^{iat} e^{-st}\right| \le \left| e^{iat}\right| \left| e^{-st}\right| \le e^{-st}$
>
> as $\left| e^{iat} \right|=1$
>   where $a,s,t \in \mathbb{R}$

I thought the last part of the inequality should read:

> $\left| e^{iat}\right| \left| e^{-st}\right| = e^{-st}$

since $\left| e^{-st}\right|$ is always positive.

I am also not sure how the middle expression of the inequality is arrived at. I do know that:
$$ \begin{align} a,b \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow & \left|ab\right| = \left| a \right| \left|b\right|\end{align}$$
By the property of the absolute value function.

But in this case, the left hand side of the inequality is the modulus of a complex number so I am not sure if the above rule still applies.I'm also not able to come up with a geometric argument to justify why the inequality must be true.

Please help me see why the given inequality must be true especially why it has to be a weak inequality instead of an equality.

Comment: I think you are right since $|exp(st)|$ is real.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's equal, since complex norm is also multiplicative!